# Как реализовать календарь на wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

День добрый! Очень прошу помочь, т.к. дедлайн близко, а делать надо быстро и без заморочек. Нужен календарь на WP, чтобы отображение было такого вида
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть кто-то подскажет плагин? Или код для реализации?

Comment: Посмотрите, вроде простенький календарик на jquery https://designmodo.com/calendar-jquery-css3/

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это понятно, что просто календарь вывести не проблема...А как привязать выбор даты к отображению записи, прикрепленной к этой дате?

Comment: http://zabuto.com/dev/calendar/examples/index.html

http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен плагин [Modern Events Calenda](https://codecanyon.net/item/modern-events-calendar-responsive-event-scheduler-booking-for-wordpress/17731780). У него есть [вид](http://webnus.net/modern-events-calendar/full-calendar/) отображения как у вас на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, огромное!! ТО что нужно!